# payment mangement in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, billing, in-app-billing

I am new to iphone , in some i phone apps like

["The Times of India iPhone app"](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/iPhone-application/mobileapp/7625215.cms?mob=1)
 they ill give us online news papers which are monthly payable in that suppose we dont pay for a month they ill stop the service,,i wanted to know how they are managing the payment & all,,  can any buddy give me some information about that

thanx in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subscription based in-App Purchase tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412020/subscription-based-in-app-purchase-tutorial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of subscription models when you create an IAP.

**Non-Renewing Subscription (THIS is what TOI App uses)**
This is used for offering services with a limited duration (A month in this TOI app case). An example of this would be a magazine or newspaper that requires users to renew their own subscriptions. Non-renewing subscriptions can still be offered, but auto-renewable subscriptions are now preferred for the following reasons:

When creating an auto-renewable subscription, you can easily set up the various durations that you want to offer. Non-renewing subscriptions do not have this feature, so you must provide the information some other way. As this is often done in the display name, you end up with a separate listing for every possible duration. By contrast, auto-renewable subscriptions allow you to have a single listing where the user simply chooses one of the durations that you offer.

Because a non-renewing subscription requires a user to renew each time, your app must contain code that recognizes when the subscription is due to expire. It must also prompt the user to purchase a new subscription. An auto-renewable subscription eliminates these steps.

As part of iOS, an auto-renewable subscription will automatically be delivered to all devices associated with the user’s Apple ID. To make device-syncing available for a non-renewing subscription, you would have to create your own delivery system.

[Tutorial By Neil North - Objective-C](https://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial)

**Auto-Renewable Subscriptions**
An auto-renewable In-App Purchase subscription allows the user to purchase in-app content for a set duration of time. At the end of that duration the subscription will renew itself, unless the user opts out. An example of an auto-renewable subscription would be a magazine or newspaper that takes advantage of the auto-renewing functionality built into iOS.

Auto-renewable subscriptions will be delivered to all devices associated with the user’s Apple ID. When you create an auto-renewable subscription in iTunes Connect, you begin by selecting the duration(s) that you will offer. When a duration ends, the App Store will automatically renew the subscription. Note that if the user has opted out of this functionality, the subscription will expire at the end of that duration. You must make sure that your app can determine whether a subscription is currently active and renewable.

[Link on steps to implement auto renew subscriptions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW2)

You can possibly specify the duration to make it a non renewable subscription.

Comment: @ Pranav if u give some example codes which uses this subscription,,would be help full to me,,thanx in advance